# Natural and formal languages

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, formal-languages, propositional-calculus

I'm going to have to take the course [Logic for Computer Science](http://www-e.openu.ac.il/courses/20466.htm) at some point and everyone says both the book and the lectures are horrible.

I'm looking for a book that covers the course material in a manner understandable to a first / second year compSci student :

> Topics: Introduction – natural and formal languages; The propositional
>   language; Propositional calculus; The predicate language; Predicate
>   calculus and its completeness; The incompleteness of arithmetic;
>   Multi-sorted logic and second-order logic; Herbrand term models;
>   Logical foundation for databases; Modal and temporal logic for program
>   verification.

Comment: Abebooks have good prices, but I just realized your location is Israel. (you might have to check which sellers have better prices around that area)

Comment: @Robert: Just curious -- what's the book?

Comment: @DavidLewis It's a book in Hebrew authored and published by the Israel Open University.  Most of their books are pretty decent, but I've heard lot's of bad things about this particular one.

Comment: @KVRaman I usually order my books from amazon as it usually turns out to be the cheapest option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Computability and Logic by Boolos, Burgess, and Jefferey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521701465) covers all of the material in your course and is written for people without a strong background or interest in mathematics. It's also very popular. I've personally only skimmed parts of it. [A list of errata and hints for odd-numbered solutions](http://www.princeton.edu/~jburgess/ManualA.pdf) is available from one of the authors.

The best introduction to logic that you could hope for is [Hodges' Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0141003146). He's hilarious, an amazing expositor, and there are solutions to every problem in the back, so it's perfect for self-study. It covers propositional and predicate logic and a few other topics, which is a big chunk of your course but not all of it. It is, however, the first chunk and the most important to understand well. I would get this and read it for fun before looking at any others. It's ~$13, small, and reads very quickly.

If you mention some textbooks or authors that you have enjoyed, I can possibly make more recommendations.

Cheers, Rachel

Comment: I enjoyed Velleman's book, "How to Prove It" http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521675995/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1332318093&sr=1-1

Comment: Does the book provide answers for a reasonable portion of it's problems?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes, I don't know if Boolos' book has solutions in it, but Hodges has complete solutions for every problem. The Boolos book is popular enough that you can find material online from courses that use it. For example, I just found this manual (by one of the authors) of hints for odd-#ed problems online: http://www.princeton.edu/~jburgess/ManualA.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Check [this book by Howard Pospesel](http://tinyurl.com/7ur6ngt) and Functional Programming by [Greg Michaelson](http://tinyurl.com/7h7szaj). I know these are good.

Comment: Do they cover all the material outlined in my question?